# I need to fetch data from json script inside a list tag

Tags: java, json, selenium

I need to fetch Json variable values inside the `li` tag like `numberOfRecommendations` which is `3`

```
<li data-extra="{&quot;hook&quot;:&quot;LFWB Hypertension&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;This patient does not have Diabetes.  There we can treat with a calcium-channel blocker.&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;detail&quot;,&quot;source&quot;:{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;{\&quot;orgName\&quot;:\&quot;Liver Foundation\&quot;,\&quot;cdsCardId\&quot;:3,\&quot;cardName\&quot;:\&quot;This patient does not have Diabetes.  There we can treat with a calcium-channel blocker.\&quot;,\&quot;author\&quot;:\&quot;Dr. Abhishek Das\&quot;,\&quot;ifRecommendedByCurrentUser\&quot;:true,\&quot;ruleName\&quot;:\&quot;Systolic Blood Pressure greater than 140 without Diabetes History\&quot;,\&quot;serviceName\&quot;:\&quot;LFWB Hypertension\&quot;,\&quot;numberOfRecommendations\&quot;:3,\&quot;uuid\&quot;:\&quot;219470ab-37a9-4fac-94b0-09cb34fb4e19\&quot;}&quot;}}" style="" xpath="1">This patient does not have Diabetes.  There we can treat with a calcium-channel blocker.<br><label style="color: white; font-weight: normal;">aaaa</label><label style="color: grey; float: right; font-weight: normal;">Dr. Abhishek Das, LFWB Hypertension</label><label style="color: white; font-weight: normal; float: right;">---</label><label style="color: rgb(30, 136, 229); float: right; font-weight: normal;">3  </label><img src="resources/images/headshots/recommended.png" width="15" height="15" style="border-radius: 50%; display: inline-block; margin-right: 5px; float: right;"></li>
```

Comment: I edited your question a bit, because your html code was not visible. Can you please elaborate what you have tried, how you want to fetch that variable and what you intend to do in Java?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I haven't actually tried. I'm new to selenium and I'm testing my website. So I need to get the values from the json variables inside the tag. I can usually do that by using xpath, id, or className but I need someway to point to the json inside the <li> tag

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code, this will help you to get the attribute **"data-extra"** and from that, you can extract whatever field you want.

**Step 1:**
 Get the data-extra field which contains the JSON response.

```
String jsonStr = driver.findElement(By.tagName("li")).getAttribute("data-extra");
System.out.println(jsonStr);
```

**Step 2:**
 Now we need to clean the JSON response as it contains extra backslash and double-quotes.

```
String jsonFormattedString = jsonStr.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
jsonFormattedString = jsonFormattedString.replace("\"{", "{");
jsonFormattedString = jsonFormattedString.replace("\"}}", "}}");
System.out.println(jsonFormattedString);
```

**Step 3:**
 Now we need to parse JSON and extract the **numberOfRecommendations** key field from the JSON response.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonFormattedString);
JSONObject source = jsonObject.getJSONObject("source");
JSONObject label = source.getJSONObject("label");
int numberOfRecommendations = label.getInt("numberOfRecommendations");
System.out.println(numberOfRecommendations);
```

**Note:** As you have not mentioned the complete **HTML**, I have assumed **tagName** field as "**li**".